# getting date in sparql from dbpedia

Tags: wikipedia, sparql, dbpedia

I want to extract the release date of some specific movies.
The sparql query, I am using is:
Not even one query is giving me any answer
Is there something wrong becoz date is returned in some format?
Could you tell me any thing wat is going wrong

```
SELECT ?star
WHERE { 
<http://dbpedia.org/page/Chances_Are_%28film%29> dbpedia-owl:releaseDate ?star
}


SELECT ?star
WHERE { 
<http://dbpedia.org/page/Cages> dbpprop:releaseDate ?star
}



SELECT ?star
WHERE { 
<http://dbpedia.org/page/Los_que_no_deben_nacer> dbpprop:released ?star
}
```

Comment: why don't you accept any answers to your questions? This behaviour discourages people to help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URI you are using for the Movie resource is wrong - you should replace "page" with "resource": http://dbpedia.org/resource/Chances_Are_%28film%29

You can see that the query getting the results you need [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20?star%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Chances_Are_%2528film%2529%3E%20dbpedia-owl%3areleaseDate%20?star%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=0&debug=on).

Note that the actual resource URI is the one with "resource" on it. The one with the "page" is the one you are redirected to when you resolve the original one in a browser. So in future SPARQL queries use "resource" instead of page.